# Computing ratio with two tables with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression

Table A

| date | flight | airport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-10-01 | oneway | ATL, GA |
| 2012-10-01 | oneway | LAX, CA |
| 2012-10-01 | oneway | SAN, CA |
| 2012-10-01 | oneway | DTW, MI |
| 2012-10-02 | round | SFO, CA |

Table B

| date | temp | precip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-10-01 | 67 | 0.02 |
| 2012-10-01 | 65 | 0.32 |
| 2012-10-01 | 86 | 0.18 |
| 2012-10-01 | 87 | 0.04 |
| 2012-10-02 | 78 | 0.24 |

The actual tables have more than 100k rows.

Exepected outcome has two columns temp and ratio

For each temp, I am trying to get the a ratio of flight = oneway where airport have "CA" in it.
I need to first filter rows that the average of precip is greater than 0.2 and cast ratio to interger.

I tried to join on date and group by temp that is having average precip < 0.2 but I am getting fixed wrong value on ratio.

How can I do CTE or CASE WHEN to merge these two tables to compute ratio?

Ratio is should be the (total count of all rows where flight = 'oneway' per each temperature after all filtering) / (total counts of rows)

Comment: I do not understand what the result of ratio should be. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Ratio is should be the (total count of all rows where flight = 'oneway' per each temperature after all filtering) / (total counts of rows). After applying all the conditions, it should have two columns: (temp, ratio) and aggregated temp per rows and their respective ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query below I join A and B records over their `Date` matching as well as `B.airport` ending with `CA`, grouped by temperature. The total number of such pairs is the result of `COUNT(*)` that I divide with. The value I am dividing is the number of items from the pairs which have a `oneway` flight. It's possible that I did not fully understand the question, in which case we may need to move the airport criteria from the where into the case-when.

```
SELECT b.temp,
       CAST(SUM(
           CASE
               WHEN A.flight = 'oneway'
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END
       ) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(*)
FROM A
JOIN B
ON A.`Date` = B.`Date` AND
   B.airport LIKE '%CA'
GROUP BY B.temp
```

Comment: I tried this to the actual data but  I get 0s on the ratio column when I compute.

Comment: @meancomu can you create a SQL Fiddle with sample data where this can be reproduced and explain the expected result? I think the issue must be something that we can fix, but I need to see the issue in order to provide further help.

Comment: Your getting 0s due to the integer division. You need to cast one or both of the operands to `REAL`

Comment: @nnichols thanks for pointing that out! Adjusted my answer accordingly.